# How to create custom VerifyReadyDlg with Wix?

Tags: wix, wix3

How to create a such dialog in Wix Setup? It was implemented by default in Inno Setup but I am thinking now how to do same in Wix. My main question is how to create disabled text area with describing what should be installed.

It should to be done in this way: User pick on previous page what he would to install extra (desktop icon or Start Menu folder etc) by clicking on checkboxes (checkboxes is set some properties) and then user able to see what will be installed on next page.

Example:

[image: Example]

I have started to create dialog but I have no idea how to create a text area

```
<Dialog Id="CustomVerifyReadyDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] - Setup">
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes"
            Text="{\DlgTitleFont}Ready to Install"/>
    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes"
            Text="Setup is now ready to begin installing [ProductName] on your computer."/>
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="SecondDescription" Type="Text" X="25" Y="65" Width="340" Height="30" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes"
            Text="Click Install to continue with the installation, or click Back if you want to review or change any settings."/>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [scrollable text control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/scrollabletext-control) for this puropse.

Should be something like that + you might use properties from [previous dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602336/wix-set-property-from-previous-dialog) or [custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388795/using-a-wix-custom-action-to-set-a-propertys-value) for you dialog.

```
<Control Id="Title" Type="ScrollableText">
   <Text> SOMECUSTOMPROPERTY </Text>
</Control>
```

[Here's](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/a-single-dialog/) a doc about dialogs in general.